# Relationship between 2 quantities when a condition is given

Tags: inequality

It is given that $ |x|y>x|y|$.

Can we determine the relationship between $(x+y)^2$ and $(x-y)^2$ ?

Comment: Sure.  The original inequality can be used to deduce the signs of $x$ and $y$.  From that, it should be possible to relate the two expressions of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given condition it is evident that $ x$ and $y$ have opposite signs.

Thus we have $$(x-y)^2 \ge ( x+y)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If the left-hand side is zero so is the right hand side, and if the left-hand side is negative both sides are equal. So the left-hand side must be positive, whence $y$ is positive. The two sides are then different only if $x\lt 0$.

Then $$(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy\lt 0$$